# Sorting 2D assoc array after field in inner array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, 2d

I have a PHP array containing assoc arrays like this:

```
Array(

[0] => ([id], [title], [votes]...),

[1] => ([id], [title], [votes],

....

)
```

I'm trying to sort the outer array after the inner array's number of votes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
usort(
    $myArray,
    function ($a, $b) {
        if ($a['votes'] == $b['votes']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['votes'] < $b['votes']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
);
```